# Checking if number=ONE, TWO, or THREE + Adding if number= Is NOT Set

Tags: php

Heres my code so far:

```
$onetwothree = (isset($_GET['number']) && (
    $_GET['number'] == 'one' ||
    $_GET['number'] == 'two' ||
    $_GET['number'] == 'three'));
```

This displays content if `?number=one`, `?number=two`, `?number=three` but how do i also display content if there is no `number=` in the url?

Comment: Check `!$onetwothree`?

Comment: `if (!isset($_GET['number'])) { display content here }`?

Comment: append: `||
    $_GET['country'] == ''` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 this sounds closest to what im trying to do, this would mean `number=` is empty correct? what i want is if there is no `number=` at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method would be to go with an extra condition:

```
if (!isset($_GET['country']) || $onetwothree) {
    // display content
}
```

If you want to display *different* content based on the value:

```
if (isset($_GET['number'])) {
    if (!isset($_GET['country'])) {
        // display content
    } else if (in_array($_GET['country'], array('one', 'two', 'three')) {
        // display other content
    }
}
```

I took a shortcut and used `in_array()` in the second example; it will make things a bit easier in the future if you ever want to expand the list of accepted values (instead of adding more `$_GET['country'] == 'xxxx'` lines)